# Calc with format number

Tags: numbers, format, podio, calc

I am having a problem in formatting numbers. I am getting a string concatenation instead of the numerical sum.

I have attached the screenshot of the problem.

Help me please. Thanks.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vv5doL2QByU_54kPDoKFRvqj6aaSRxbg

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-BktFl_j9H3tzKGysDoDlr4nB7cDVEGu

I need the sum of 5 + 5 + 5, but the result is 555 instead of 15.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you join the Number array it will be converted a string. Please update  as below

```
var total = @All of Suma OD.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
total - [Your other calculation logics]
```